# Flash 3D Libraries: which one is most efficient?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, 3d

Support of *cinematics*, *shadows* and *import* from common externals formats are *advantages*. Could you say some words about libraries you used?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Away3D is well regarded. It supports shadows, import from common formats and various cameras. See a list of features here:
http://away3d.com/features/

It also supports Adobe's Molehill (for GPU rendering) http://away3d.com/comments/away3d-adobes-new-3d-api-molehill

Comment: While there are other choices, I'd say away3d is the best way to go.

Comment: I agree and I would focus on using the latest beta version since the release of Flash 11 is right around the corner. I have been using the beta version for a 3D project that is also using the kinect with great results.